# How do I ignore if case condition is not met in SQL?

Tags: sql, case

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc) <=10 THEN name ELSE, --ignore-- END AS name
    COUNT(*) as COUNT
FROM person
GORUP BY name
```

So I'm simply trying to get top 10 occurencies of a person in the list. But I only want the top 5, are there any ways to make not select lines that falls outside top 5? I know I can make a nested select, but I want to know if it's possible to replace the --ignore-- with something that ignores?

Comment: I have removed the conflicting tags; SQL Server <> PostgreSQL. Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using (you need to [edit] your question to correct the tag(s)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the upper limit of 5

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc) <=10 THEN name ELSE '' END AS name
FROM ...
LIMIT 5
```